# Java JTree: only add child if there are no other childs

Tags: java, jtree

I have a JTree with a root and several nodes. When the user adds a node to another node with no children, the child is added. But when there are already nodes in the selected node, the node can't be added.

This is my code:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode =  DefaultMutableTreeNode)treeExpertises.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
selectedNode.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(newDomain), selectedNode.getChildCount());
```

I also tried this with the same result:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)treeExpertises.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
selectedNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(newDomain));
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer:

```
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)treeExpertises.getModel();
model.nodeStructureChanged(selectedNode);
```